# Install and use pcalg in R on Mac M1 from Terminal

Tags: r, rpy2

I am trying to install and use `pcalg` ([details](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pcalg/pcalg.pdf)) in `R` (R-4.2.1-arm64.pkg) from terminal using the following commands:

```
install.packages("pcalg", dependencies = TRUE)
library(pcalg)
```

I get this error after the second step:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘pcalg’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
there is no package called ‘graph’
```

The first command gives the following message:

```
Warning: dependencies ‘graph’, ‘RBGL’, ‘Rgraphviz’ are not available
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/pcalg_2.7-7.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 6500355 bytes (6.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 6.2 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/2b/q__z5z855qq_36mk8xf33b380000gp/T//RtmpVzspPi/downloaded_packages
```

Is there any missing step here? I want to eventually do this through rpy2 for python.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the package's [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/package=pcalg) I see that graph, RBGL and Rgraphviz are not on CRAN but on Bioconductor. You need to install them with the [BiocManager](https://www.bioconductor.org/install/).

Comment: Can you suggest how to do this with Python through `rpy2`? This doesn't work: `import rpy2.robjects as robjects
robjects.r('BiocManager::install("pcalg")')
robjects.r('library(pcalg)')`

Comment: No, I cannot. I don't program in python. But you have not read my answer carefully. pcalg is not a Bioconductor package. It is on CRAN. It has dependencies that are Bioconductor packages.

Comment: Agreed, however, I was able to use functions from the package after installing them using `BiocManager::install('pcalg')` in `R` for versions 4.1.0 and 4.2.1, the installation was giving errors when done using `install.package('pcalg', dependencies=TRUE)`